# This diagram serves to determine the components of a data entry in my database. What is the name of this type of diagram?

Tags: database-theory, databases

To properly insert a data entry in my database, I have to reach the last box in this diagram. A box represents either a flag or a data structure that participates in determining a single entry. What is the name of this type of diagram?

Alternatively, what do you call the procedure of making such a diagram?

(cross-posted from Database Administrators)

[image]